# Find general solution for $y'' + (1/x)y' = x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I used the quadratic formula to get two roots, $r = \frac{1}{x}, 0$ so a homogeneous solution would be $y = c_1 + c_2e$. Now to find the non homogeneous solution, I am trying to use undetermined coefficients method. I tried $y = A + Bx$ and $y = A + Bx + Cx^2$ but neither of them worked. I am out of ideas for what to do from here. At this point I am just guessing different things. Is there a more systematic approach I can take?

Comment: the quadratic formula approach only works if the coefficients are constants

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$y'' + (1/x)y' = x$$
multiply by $x$:
$$xy'' + y' = x^2$$
Rewrite as:
$$(xy')' = x^2$$
Integrate.

Comment: I integrated and got $xy' = \frac{1}{3}x^3 \to y' = \frac{1}{3}x^2$. Then I integrated again to get $y = x^3$, but when I verify it is a solution it is wrong.

Comment: @EvanKim, your second integration is wrong. Also, don't forget constants.

Comment: Isn't it $y' = \frac{1}{3} \int x^2 dx = \frac{3}{3}x^3 + C$, but C just disappears when I verify the solution

Comment: @EvanKim Perform the integration correctly $xy'=\frac {x^3}3+c_1 $ Divide by $x$ then integrate again  $y'=\frac {x^2}3 +\frac {c_1} x$ Integrate again...

Comment: @EvanKim  You should finally get $y=\frac {x^3}9+c_1 \ln |x|+c_2$